# CSS hover:transform moves element in left side instead of toward me

Tags: css, hover, element, transform

Please help me.
CSS (hover:transform) moves element  and  in 1,2 and 4 rows in left side.
In 3rd row, everything is ok. One differance in 3rd row: text-align: center.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gawg5.jpg)

I tried out change <transform: scale(2)> on <font-size 200%>. Result was even worse. The hover didn't work altogether.
I expect all hover elements move toward me.
Thank you in advance.

Snippet of code:

```
h2, h3{
    transition: 0.5s;
}
h2:hover, h3:hover{
    transform: scale(2)
 }
```

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1>h1 head</h1>
    <h2>h2 head</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>h2</h2>
    <h3>h3 head</h3>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>h2 head</h2>
    <h3>h3 head</h3>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>h2 head</h2>
    <h3>h3 head</h3>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML as well.

Comment: thank for interest to my prolem. I added that to description of problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the text are all left-aligned and their [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is at the very center (by default), it just seems to you that they move to left.

ASCII art explanation (not to scale):

```
Before:
                    Viewport
          ┌───────────────────────────┐
          │                           │
          │ ┌───────────────────────┐ │
          │ │ HEADER                │ │
          │ └───────────────────────┘ │
          │                           │
          │                           │
          │                           │
          │                           │
          └───────────────────────────┘

After:
                    Viewport
          ┌───────────────────────────┐
          │                           │
┌─────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────┐
│  │ │ ┌── ┌─┐ ┌─\ ┌── ┌─\            │         │
│  ├─┤ ├─  ├─┤ │ │ ├─  ├─/            │         │
│  │ │ └── │ │ └─/ └── │ │            │         │
└─────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────┘
          │                           │
          │                           │
          └───────────────────────────┘
```

```
Before:
                    Viewport
          ┌───────────────────────────┐
          │                           │
          │ ┌───────────────────────┐ │
          │ │        HEADER         │ │
          │ └───────────────────────┘ │
          │                           │
          │                           │
          │                           │
          │                           │
          └───────────────────────────┘

After:
                    Viewport
          ┌───────────────────────────┐
          │                           │
┌─────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────┐
│         │  │ │ ┌── ┌─┐ ┌─\ ┌── ┌─\  │         │
│         │  ├─┤ ├─  ├─┤ │ │ ├─  ├─/  │         │
│         │  │ │ └── │ │ └─/ └── │ │  │         │
└─────────┼───────────────────────────┼─────────┘
          │                           │
          │                           │
          └───────────────────────────┘
```

Live demo explanation (to scale):

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

h2, h3 {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

h2:hover, h3:hover {
  transform: scale(2)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>h2 head</h2>
  <h3>h3 head</h3>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>h2 head</h2>
  <h3>h3 head</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, very easy, very simple. Why i couldn't guess about it. Thank you for help. I changed width of tags h2 and h3 and now that looks as i expected. Thanks))